# ASP.NET MVC4 Google oAuth

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth

Im trying to configure Google oAuth in an MVC 4 Project. Its quite straight forward out of the box as per [Hanslemans Excellent Video](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates)

Im able to register, log on, log off etc, but the only information I have is the email address. Id like to be able to get the First Name, Last Name and Image from Google

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/extra-information-from-oauth-openid-provider.aspx) outlines that it is possible - but when I run through it all that is available is the email address. This is obvious as this is all we asked for permission for.

So my question is how do I ask for more information from Google and the how do I access it. I know its possible writing my own oAuth access but I assume its possible using the out of the box MVC 4 code.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: I'm in the same boat, Extradata just has email address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this falls under a bug that is in DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet version="4.0.3.12153" package. You need to write your own customer provider and then you can get the data from that

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx

You should be able to use GetExtraData to get the data you are looking for!